# How do I use AutoMapper to convert a nullable decimal?

Tags: c#, linq, decimal, automapper, nullable

So my code appears as:

```
CreateMap<EntityOne, ModelOne>()
.ForPath(dest => dest.Field1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Field1))
```

Both Field1 are nullable decimals, I want to be able to convert the value to 2 decimal places as I'm mapping. Think my best attempt has been:

```
CreateMap<EntityOne, ModelOne>()
                .ForPath(dest => dest.Field1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Field1.HasValue ? Math.Round((decimal)src.Field1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) : null))
```

The error I get is:

> The type arguments for method 'IPathConfigurationExpression<EntityOne, ModelOne, decimal?>.MapFrom(Expression<Func<EntityOne, TSourceMember>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can solve this by just casting the result of `Math.Round` to a nullable decimal:

```
opt.MapFrom(src => src.Field1.HasValue 
         ? (decimal?)Math.Round((decimal)src.Field1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) 
         : null)
```

This way the call *should* be able to be "inferred from the usage"

Comment: An alternative would be `src.Field1.HasValue ? Math.Round((decimal)src.Field1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) : default(decimal?)`